# RoR: rake db:schema:load RAILS_ENV=production error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting the following error when i try to create the production db in Rails:

```
>rake db:schema:load RAILS_ENV=production --trace
rake db:schema:load RAILS_ENV=production --trace
(in C:/Users/user/Documents/Aptana Studio/truping)
** Invoke db:schema:load (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- application
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:155:in `require'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:262:in `require_or_load'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:221:in `depend_on'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:133:in `require_dependency'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:18:in `define_dispatcher_callbacks'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:182:in `call'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:182:in `evaluate_method'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `each'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `send'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:277:in `run_callbacks'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.2.2/lib/initializer.rb:559:in `send'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.2.2/lib/initializer.rb:559:in `prepare_dispatcher'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.2.2/lib/initializer.rb:173:in `process'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.2.2/lib/initializer.rb:112:in `send'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.2.2/lib/initializer.rb:112:in `run'
C:/Users/rrevi/Documents/Aptana Studio/truping/config/environment.rb:13
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:153:in `require'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:153:in `require'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.2.2/lib/tasks/misc.rake:3
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.4/lib/rake.rb:617:in `call'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.4/lib/rake.rb:617:in `execute'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.4/lib/rake.rb:612:in `each'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.4/lib/rake.rb:612:in `execute'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.4/lib/rake.rb:578:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:238:in `synchronize'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.4/lib/rake.rb:571:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.4/lib/rake.rb:588:in `invoke_prerequisites'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.4/lib/rake.rb:585:in `each'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.4/lib/rake.rb:585:in `invoke_prerequisites'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.4/lib/rake.rb:577:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:238:in `synchronize'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.4/lib/rake.rb:571:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.4/lib/rake.rb:564:in `invoke'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.4/lib/rake.rb:2027:in `invoke_task'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.4/lib/rake.rb:2005:in `top_level'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.4/lib/rake.rb:2005:in `each'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.4/lib/rake.rb:2005:in `top_level'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.4/lib/rake.rb:2044:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.4/lib/rake.rb:1999:in `top_level'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.4/lib/rake.rb:1977:in `run'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.4/lib/rake.rb:2044:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.4/lib/rake.rb:1974:in `run'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.4/bin/rake:31
C:/ruby/bin/rake:19:in `load'
C:/ruby/bin/rake:19
```

Can anyone help? Am I missing a Gem?

Comment: What is on line 13 in your environment.rb?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you migrated  a Rails 2.2 application to Rails 2.3. I ran into this issue sometime back but it was resolved when I put a copy of application_controller.rb as application.rb . Not sure what the real solution was but it will get your app working.

Comment: I concur this is the issue -- any chance your config/environments/production.rb has a different RAILS_VERSION declaration inside?  From the error, it almost looks like you've gone backwards from Rails 2.3 to Rails 2.2 -- you may have an application_controller.rb, but the system wants application.rb.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing a gem. How did you installed rails?

Also, do you have migrations ready and valid?

Answer (score 0):

Raj,

The problem was that I migrated a Rails 2.3.2 application to a Rails 2.2.2 environment. I fixed problem by updating rails gems to Rails 2.3.2 for the application project.

Like you said, Rails 2.2.2 looks for application.rb where as Rails 2.3.2 looks for application_controller.rb

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

my ISP only supports 2.2.2 so I created a symlink to application.rb which worked :)